# AppController vs Component

Tags: cakephp, components, controllers

I have a set of functions shared between **all** my controllers and I'm doubting whether I should place them in a component, loaded from every controller (or from AppController), or add them in the AppController class (with visibility set to `protected`), so all the controllers inherit them.

Which is the better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a component is recommended, IMO. Components are lazy loaded and also help keep your code look clean. Also in use cases where you need access to some sort of model data, you DO NOT want to load models and call them from AppController!

Comment: Not to mention, your project might expand to have some controllers that don't need it - you never know.

Comment: This is a bit offtopic, but how does it work the lazy loading of components? I mean, what should I call? Doing `$this->ComponentName->function()` I obviously get an error.

Comment: Is the component loaded? Does ComponentName::function() work?